# Handling Service Disconnection - Queuing Calls

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, design-patterns

I posted another question recently about a problem i was having with some pattern code, and it was suggested to me that i might not be using the correct pattern to solve my problem in the first place, as such i thought i would post this question.

The problem i'm trying to solve is such:

I have a WPF client that will be run from remote offices, it's pretty simple handling data entry and editing, they connect to WCF services hosted at our end (before going to a DB). The problem is that the client connection is unreliable and can drop out constantly.

So, my idea was to use the command pattern, and queue the command (such as update, delete) and when the connection returns execute the commands.

However, it was suggested that the command pattern might not be a good fit here. So my questions would be:

Is the command pattern a good match?
If not, why?

Comment: I note from your other comments that your connection may be down for multiple hour periods. If you're looking at dropouts of that length I'd be extremely concerned about the application being shut down. With that in mind, you might want to consider local storage of your requests - push everything to an intermediary DB or XML on the client side, then use a background process or service to work through that queue. When the connection's available it should still be workably quick, otherwise everything stays in situ until the application's next run.

Comment: That is a good point, but would that not add quite a bit of complexity with checking to ensure the local data is not outdated? or would you always pull from the services when a connection is available, ignoring the local data until the connection is lost?

Comment: There's not much that's easy about that level of service interruption unfortunately. Consider Friday@4.59pm - everyone's going home and someone inputs something critical. The connection dies. Do they wait/leave the system running for 2 hours to confirm the transaction? If your data is in any way important you're going to have to manage a large amount of integrity checking on both ends. Not sure I'm aware of a way around that.

Comment: Yeah, we considered a transaction log, just keeping a record of the procedure calls that we could replay when the connection returns, but that still leaves the problem of dealing with sql errors and the like.

Answer (score 0):

The command pattern will help you to be sure that "all or nothing" of your modifications will be taken into account. Because you will send only one request to your WCF service, which will unstack all the "commands" and reply by OK/KO.

But, if your form only exposes one object (if your viewmodel presents only one model), then you just have to call one update WCF method MyClassService.SaveMyObjectAsync(myObject). And I don't understand why you would use the command pattern.

Comment: The point is, that the connection could be down for a couple of hours. If the user edits a couple of models, adds a few more i wanted all of those to be stacked up ready for sending to the service, how would using your method help with that?

Comment: OK. I think I understand.
So, you have to save your command locally (in a local DB or serialized in a file) until the WCF treatment is finished and validated.
It looks to be a good idea.